# rand() function Bionic vs glibc

Tags: android, gcc, random, glibc, bionic

I found that `rand()` function from bionic does't work without including `stdlib.h`

```
extern int rand(void);

static void foo()
{
    int a = rand();
}

int main()
{
  foo()
  return 0;
}
```

Results for `glibc`:
Compilation successful

Results for `bionic`:
Compilation unsuccessful

```
error: undefined reference to 'rand'
```

In `bionic` sources we have following implementation:

```
static __inline__ int rand(void) {
    return (int)lrand48();
}
```

Why it works for `glibc` but not for `bionic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glibc's rand() is a "normal" function located in a library. I suspect you're getting a warning about the symbol not being defined from the compiler (which cannot find it), but since the function exists in a library, the link stage can still find and link to it.

bionic's rand() is a `static inline` in your header file, that means it's not even defined unless the header file is included. Since the compiler cannot find it without the include and it does not exist in any library that the linker can resolve it from, compilation will fail at the linking stage.

Comment: Why `static inline` means that i must use `.h` file, i can't found any confirmation in standard

Answer (score 2):

You will get the answer if you just compare bionic and glibc sources of rand function: https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/include/stdlib.h and
http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/rand.c;hb=glibc-2.15#l26

You can see that in `bionic` library it inlined in header file so without `.h` file you can't use it.And in glibc it is separated like most of the functions. The reason is obvious I think - `bionic` library was developed specially for use in embedded and mobile devices with memory and speed limits, so less code and inline optimizations is useful.

Comment: Do you have a link to a standard where is written that I must use `.h` file when function is `static inline`

Comment: @Pepelac Please look at §3.2/3, §7.1.2 §7.1.3/4.